# How to run Cypress tests with docker on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, cypress

I am trying to run Cypress tests with docker on Windows.
I am using [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/)  as a guide.

I am getting an error like this: "Your configFile is invalid: /e2e/cypress.config.ts"

[Error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWwE.png)

I was expecting to run Cypress tests with docker but I get unknown error, I tried to search this error but I found nothing related to it.

Comment: please specify the base url in cypress.config.ts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.